# When to use @Transactional annotation in unit testing?

Tags: spring, junit, spring-junit

i have a junit test class which its configuration is as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ WebContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class })
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@DirtiesContext
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = {
        SpringConfig.class, SpringTestingConfig.class,
        SpringLocalContainerJPAConfig.class, CustomConfiguration.class })
```

and the test methods is calling service methods and the service class has the annotation `@Transactional` for some reason, when i make test case for service method it fails and give me the exception `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist` as in this post:
[org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist with H2 in memory database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887055/org-hibernate-persistentobjectexception-detached-entity-passed-to-persist-with/17894200#comment26146894_17894200)
and to fix this exception i have to annotate the test class with the annotation `@Transactional` although in the managed bean when i invoke same code it works fine, so my question is why `@Transactional` is required sometimes in test and when i should annotate my test class with `@Transactional` considering that service layer has this annotation.

Comment: Could you post your test method and your managed bean code snippet?

Comment: @Hippoom here's the link for full example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887055/org-hibernate-persistentobjectexception-detached-entity-passed-to-persist-with/17894200#comment26146894_17894200